Yeoman quickstart for VSCode extension doesn't work
I'm following the quickstart guide for creating a VSCode extension with Yeoman. I ran yo code, started the extension debug window, and... the "Hello World" command just doesn't show up. (On MacOS.)
I've tried this by selecting both yarn and npm as package managers, same result.
I've also verified that I have a high enough VSCode version, and regardless, I saw no difference when setting the minimum required version to ^0.0.0.
Not sure how to proceed from here. The quickstart guide does look out of date. For example, I saw these differences in the Yeoman prompts:
# ? What type of extension do you want to create? New Extension (TypeScript)
# ? What's the name of your extension? HelloWorld
### Press <Enter> to choose default for all options below ###

# ? What's the identifier of your extension? helloworld
# ? What's the description of your extension? LEAVE BLANK
# ? Initialize a git repository? Yes
# ? Bundle the source code with webpack? No <---- this asked me for a specific bundler (none, webpack or esbuild)
# ? Which package manager to use? npm

# ? Do you want to open the new folder with Visual Studio Code? Open with `code`


yo version - 5.0.0
generator-code version - 1.9.0
VSCode version - 1.89.1


The issue was that I hadn't opened the extension code in its own VSCode window, which is required. Alternatively you can copy the .vscode configuration into the top-level .vscode directory for your active window, adjusting file paths as needed.
